New Outlook (2024) and web-fonts
I've been doing some various HTML emails for a platform and I'm using a 400 and 600 weight version of Inter served by Google Fonts. On basically all mail-clients including Outlook Online, I have no issue using this, but a change in Outlook suddenly only shows the bold version of the font.
Is that a known bug or is there some "hack" to solve this? Every paragraph contains both font-family and font-weight, so it should be that.
Outlook (2024) on Windows 11
Outlook (2024) on Windows 11
Outlook (web) in Microsoft Edge
Outlook (web) in Microsoft Edge
I've tried to serve from my own domain (Azure Blob) and many possible CSS changes, but nothing changes this. The odd thing is that it doesn't look like a fallback font, but actually the bold version of the Inter font.

By "Outlook (2024)" do you mean the "New" Outlook (the one that's rewritten as a WebView2 app and doesn't support VBA) or the good ol' fashioned OUTLOOK.EXE?

@Dai: The rewritten one.

You might want to try defining your custom font in a <style> block within the <head> section of your HTML email. And then after the <body> tag use this snnipet:
<body>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, p, ul, li, u, table tr, table td, a, span, table.MsoNormalTable {
            font-family: Calibri !important; 
            font-size: 11pt !important; 
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

This is a reset, ensuring that Outlook applies the specified font family and size, which may help with the rendering issue. While it primarily targets the default font in Outlook. I got this working based on this forum, I did not test with custom fonts but apparently some people got to work. Give it a try and see if it helps!
